# How to add "styled" documentation tooltip in C#?

Tags: c#, documentation

How do I add "styled" (bold, italic etc.) tips in C#? Or is there any way to do this?
PS: That code on image doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have style in the IDE? or in the "compiled" documentation?
There is no specification for documentation styling. It only depends on the Tools you use.

Answer (score 1):

The "styling" in your image is not part of the C# specification. It's just your editor (Sublime?) that does some basic parsing, and sets the text color of items it recognizes.

You can see for yourself if you open your so-called "styled" source code in a plain text editor such as TextEdit or Notepad. Even if you can see colors again, they are assigned by that software in turn.

Comment: I use VS 2010 and C#. I just want to styled hints for properties, classess etc.